# Непонятная бага с div, как можно исправить разметку?

Tags: css, html5

При обычном `div` текст не внутри блока, а выезжает за его пределы. Причем подобная ситуация только с `href`. Обычный текст внутри `div` отображается нормально.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
Разве свойства `href` как-то отдельно надо задавать?

[image: описание баги]

```css
div.myinks {
  max-width: 400px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mylinks"><a href="адрес-ссылки">asdasdasd</a></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

У Вас ошибка в именовании классов в html разметке указан класс mylinks

```
<div class="mylinks">
```

а в стилях `div.myinks`
Ваши стили не применяются, укажите одинаковые классы и все будет работать